# Why is extjs calling refresh URL when I render an element?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am creating a component, and then rendering it to a DOM object (a div).

```
    //create component
    this.p = this.createTablePanel();

    //add it to the DIV
    this.p.render(paveDIV);
```

Everything works find, it is just that there is a weird error in my console. It seems to want to go to a URL called 'refresh'.

```
GET http://this_is_where_my_local_is:8080/myWebSite/refresh 404 (Not Found)
```

This is created deep inside ExtJS :

```
GET http://lokalllhost:8080/creationWWW/refresh 404 (Not Found) ext-all-debug.js:13457 Ext.override.getStyle ext-all-debug.js:13457 Ext.override.isStyle ext-all-debug.js:13401 Element.override.fixDisplay ext-all-debug.js:18138 Element.override.setVisible ext-all-debug.js:18078 Base.implement.callParent ext-all-debug.js:4263 Ext.define.setVisible ext-all-debug.js:81417 Element.override.hide ext-all-debug.js:18154 Ext.define.constructor ext-all-debug.js:81198 constructor ext-all-debug.js:4894 Ext.define.constructor ext-all-debug.js:33170 Ext.define.makeFloating
```

(Screenshot maybe looks better)

[image]

Everything else works fine. Its just annoying to see this error in the console.

Answer (score 1):

The problem must come from elsewhere, not from the above code. Also, it is not a recommended practice to create a component and then to render it somewhere, normally you add a component to container by configuring it in `items:[]` array or calling `add()` method.

Comment: we are just adding extjs components to our existing javascript app. So we have to somehow add them. I think render() would be the only way.

Comment: Yes, it does work, but use it only as a last resort.

Comment: that `refresh` icon is also broken in the docs:
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.Button.html

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I was encountering the same problem in ExtJS 6.5.3, so I wanted to share my findings.

The problem (from our legacy code) came from some Ext.Template for a button with placeholder `background-image` style applied.

```
<span class="x-button-icon demo-icon icon-search" style="background-image: url(&quot;true&quot;);">
```

This would give us the [same kind of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhTdY.png) in the console. Getting rid of it made the error disappear.

It seems that ExtJS is trying to load the `background` url, and obviously fails.